# Android Map Overlay Issues

Tags: android, dictionary, overlays

Is there any way i can implement a zoom listener that can trigger events as soon as the zoom level changes. So far, i have managed with the onUserinteraction method manually checking for changing zoom-level.
Another thing is i to want add/remove overlays dynamically. what i,ve done so far is in the onUserinteraction method, i call a function which adds the overlays dynamically, using mapOverlays.add() function and the addition actually does happen dynamically. But somehow mapOverlays.remove() function is not removing the overlays

```
     //Function for adding first set of markers
     public void setOverlay()
{
    worldLength = World.length;
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    drawable0 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
    itemizedOverlay0 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable0);
    for (int i = 0; i < worldLength; i++)
    {
        itemizedOverlay0.addOverlay(World[i]);
    }
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay0);
    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
     //Function for adding second set of markers
     public void setOverlay1() 
     {
      mapView.setStreetView(true);
      usaLength = USA.length;
      mexicoLength = Mexico.length;
               mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        itemizedOverlay1 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable1);
        itemizedOverlay2 = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable1);


        for (int i = 0; i < usaLength; i++) {
            itemizedOverlay1.addOverlay(USA[i]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mexicoLength; i++) {
            itemizedOverlay2.addOverlay(Mexico[i]);
        }

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay1);
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay2);


    mapView.postInvalidate();

}

     public void onUserInteraction() {
   super.onUserInteraction();
   if(mapView.getZoomLevel()>3)
   {
       mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay0);
       setOverlay1();
                 //the above happens
   }
   else if(mapView.getZoomLevel()<=3 && mapOverlays.size()>5)
   {
       mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay1);
       mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlay2);
                 //the above doesn't
       setOverlay();   
   }
   else if(mapView.getZoomLevel()<=3)
   {

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement your custom zoom handler and add a listener, you need to be create your subclass of the MapView. First, let's create the interface for the `OnZoomListener`. Note that you could change the interface to suit your need, the following is just a skeleton code for you to start with

```
public interface OnZoomListener {
    /***
     * /**
     * Called when there is a zoom changes 
     * @param mapView Reference to the current map view
     * @param currentZoom The current zoom, set to -1 initially
     * @param newZoom The new zoom level
     */
     public void onZoomChanged(MapView mapView, int currentZoom, int newZoom);
}
```

Now, you need a subclass that will call this `OnZoomListener` whenever the zoom changes. Here is the skeleton code for that which is an extension of [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729255/how-to-implemennt-onzoomlistener-on-mapview)

```
public class MyMapView extends MapView {
    int oldZoomLevel=-1;
    OnZoomListener onZoomListener;

    public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyMapView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyMapView(Context context, String apiKey) {
        super(context, apiKey);
    }

    public void setOnZoomListener(OnZoomListener onZoomListener) {
        this.onZoomListener = onZoomListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        int newZoom = this.getZoomLevel();

        if (newZoom != oldZoomLevel) {
            // dispatch the listeners
            if(oldZoomLevel != -1 &&  onZoomListener != null) {
                onZoomListener.onZoomChanged(this, oldZoomLevel, newZoom);
            }

            // update the new zoom level
            oldZoomLevel = getZoomLevel();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you could use `MyMapView` in your layout instead of the standard `MapView`. Note: The code package `com.so4729255` is what I use for testing only.

```
  <com.so4729255.MyMapView
                android:id="@+id/mapview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:apiKey="YOUR API KEY"
                android:clickable="true"
        />
```

And finally add the `OnZoomListener` in your code. The code below just show the Toast for illustration of usage, you could do whatever you need to do there

```
 MyMapView mapView = (MyMapView)this.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setOnZoomListener(new OnZoomListener() {
            public void onZoomChanged(MapView mapView, int currentZoom,
                    int newZoom) {
                // implement your handler here
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(WebViewMain.this, "Zoom has changed from " + currentZoom + " to " + 
                        newZoom, 500);
                t.show();
            }
        });
```

As for your second question, as everyone has answered, calling `MapView.invalidate()` should repaint the map with its new state as it will force the View to redraw per [the API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate)

Comment: this is good, will surely try and get back, what i need know ASAP is why i am not able to remove using mapOverlays.remove(itemizedOverlayname); any immediate help would be greatly appreciated.....Thanks a million

Comment: Have you tried calling MapView.invalidate() instead of mapView.postInvalidate()? invalidate() should redraw the map immediately (at least for all the map cases that I've done before) per the documentation.

Comment: have done and its not working, i just noticed the remove method only removes the first occurence of the overlay object, but my  faulty code, adds the same overlay multiple times, hence i am not able to see the result. will fix and answer my own question properly....btw i am implementing ur zoom listener idea!!!

Answer (score 0):

well you have to refresh the map using

```
mapview.invalidate()
```

> postInvalidate posts an invalidate request on the UI-thread,  while a
>   call to invalidate() invalidates the View immediately

Answer (score 0):

When the zoom level changes, the map is redrawn so I simply put this type of functionality in my overlay's draw method, like so:

```
e@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow)
{       
    int zoom = mapv.getZoomLevel();

    switch(zoom)
    {
        case 19:
            setMarkersForZoomLevel19();
            break;
        case 18:
            setMarkersForZoomLevel18();
            break;
        case 17:
            setMarkersForZoomLevel17();
            break;
        case 16:
            setMarkersForZoomLevel16();
            break;
        default:
            // Hide the markers or remove the overlay from the map view.                
            mapv.getOverlays().clear();
    }       

    // Putting this call here rather than at the beginning, ensures that
    // the Overlay items are drawn over the top of canvas stuff e.g. route lines.
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, false);        
}
```

and when you remove an overlay, remember to call mapView.invalidate().