# How to set center of GoogleMap?

Tags: java, android

I have following task: I have been making Android application, and I need to set drawable marker into center of Map that if I move map or zoom map this marker will continue point to center of Map, won't move with Map. How can I do it?

Comment: put your code which you trying

Comment: I have made a mistake - I need to disable moving and enable zooming. But I only know how I can disable all activity for Map - map.setClickable(false). I need it because I need that Map always shows center of Map only.

Comment: you can use onTouch method for mapview and handle all things whatever you want on mapview...

Comment: How can I set listener for zooming event?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the center of map by getting the controller of map view and set its center.

```
mapView.getController().setCenter(GeoPoint);
```

Comment: I need 1 thing more: how can I disable moving of map and enable zooming of map?

Comment: You can try setClickable(false) for disable the moving and  setFocusable(true) to enable zooming.

Comment: I have made a mistake - I need to disable moving and enable zooming. But I only know how I can disable all activity for Map - map.setClickable(false). I need it because I need that Map always shows center of Map only.

Comment: How can I set listener for zooming event?

Comment: see this: it is similar with your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729255/how-to-implemennt-onzoomlistener-on-mapview  and may be you will get solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you even want to use a marker for that? It sounds like the obvious solution is to have another ImageView or ImageButton or what have you layered on top of your map with layout_gravity="center". It'll stay centred and you won't need to constantly move a marker around.